# How to include a markdown file in index.html?

Tags: pelican

In summary, I want to include a specific markdown file in a template.html.  How do I do that?

I currently have an `about.md` page which gets rendered to a `about.html` using the `page.html` template in my theme.

Instead of that, I want the `about.md` to get rendered inside of my `index.html` template.

I see how to include other templates, eg. `{% include "index-sidebar.html" %}`
But I want something like `{% include "about-rendered.html" %}` , where about-rendered.html was rendered using the about.md source.

I see in the `page.html` template, the markdown content is inserted with `{{ page.content }}`.
Perhaps there is something like `{{ about.md.content }}` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of data available to use in the templates.
This is what worked for me.

https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/themes.html#common-variables
https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/themes.html#page

```
{% for p in pages %}
{% if p.title == 'About' %}
{{p.content}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```